# How to detour a function on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, memory, hook

I made a 32 bit test program and I'm trying to detour this function (internally):

```
void Function(int number)
{
    std::cout << "Your number is: " << number << std::endl;
}
```

using this detour function that I made (which throws a SIGSEV Segmentation Fault on memcpy, even though the memory is valid and is protected with execute/read/write):

```
bool Detour(byte_t* src, byte_t* dst, size_t size)
{
    if(size < HOOK_MIN_SIZE) return false;
    mprotect(src, size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    mem_t jmpAddr = ((mem_t)dst - (mem_t)src) - HOOK_MIN_SIZE;
    byte_t CodeCave[] = { JMP, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };
    *(mem_t*)((mem_t)CodeCave + sizeof(JMP)) = jmpAddr;
    memcpy(src, CodeCave, sizeof(CodeCave));
    return true;
}
```

It is being called like this:

```
Detour((byte_t*)&Function, (byte_t*)&hkFunction, HOOK_SIZE);
```

HOOK_MIN_SIZE is equal to 5, in order to fit an assembly jump (0xE9 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00) and HOOK_SIZE is equal to 7, as it has to fit all the overwritten instructions (for a trampoline, but that doesn't matter in this case):

```
Dump of assembler code for function Function(int):
   0x5655631d <+0>:    push   ebp
   0x5655631e <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x56556320 <+3>:    push   ebx
   0x56556321 <+4>:    sub    esp,0x4
   0x56556324 <+7>:    call   0x56556220 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
```

GDB error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x565564c9 in Detour (
    src=0x5655631d <Function(int)> "U\211\345S\203\354\004\350\367\376\377\377\201\303\367+",
    dst=0x56556372 <hkFunction(int)> "U\211\345S\203\354\004\350\242\376\377\377\201â+", size=7) at main.cpp:51
51        memcpy(src, CodeCave, sizeof(CodeCave));
```

Typedefs:

```
typedef unsigned int mem_t;
typedef unsigned char byte_t;
```

What is the issue with this detour function? I already have sucessfully made my own on Windows for both 32 and 64 bit, but it seems to be different on Linux.

Comment: One wrong thing is that `sizeof(JMP)` is in bytes but you use it in `int*` pointer arithmetic. That should not cause your problem. Verify return value of `mprotect` to see if it actually worked. Note [man mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) says _"addr must be aligned to a page boundary"_ and _"EINVAL addr is not a valid pointer, or not a multiple of the system page size."_

Comment: Examples should be reproducible. Can you provide your `hkFunction`, `main`, and any other code that we'd need to compile and try this ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work! The problem was that the address was not a multiple of the system page, and I could fix it using this function instead of mprotect:

```
int ProtectMemory(mem_t address, size_t size, int protection)
{
    long pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    address = address - (address % pagesize);
    return mprotect((void*)address, size, protection);
}
```

The Detour function now looks like this:

```
bool Detour(byte_t* src, byte_t* dst, size_t size)
{
    if(size < HOOK_MIN_SIZE) return false;
    //mprotect(src, size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    int out = ProtectMemory((mem_t)src, size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
    //std::cout << out << std::endl;
    mem_t jmpAddr = ((mem_t)dst - (mem_t)src) - HOOK_MIN_SIZE;
    byte_t CodeCave[] = { JMP, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };
    *(mem_t*)((mem_t)CodeCave + sizeof(JMP)) = jmpAddr;
    memcpy(src, CodeCave, sizeof(CodeCave));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `address = address - (address % pagesize);` is a bit overcomplicated.  It's going to be a power of 2 so `address &= -pagesize` works to round down to the start of the page, i.e. clear all the offset-within-page bits of the address.  Note that you're assuming `src .. src+5` doesn't span a page boundary.  That will always be true if functions are all aligned by 16 bytes, like compilers normally do.

Comment: Also, `size` is not the arg you should be passing to `mprotect` (especially after rounding down the address).  You want to write exactly 1 page (containing the function start) no matter how large the function is.